# Multiple then conditions in a single IF loop in R

Tags: r

I'm pretty new to R and have some experience of working on it but not very fluent in it.
I have recently worked on a data-set on a big data set and using R 3.3.1 for the same. 
In the data frame(X) ,there is a column of flag type and 2 columns of numeric type,i.e., height and weight.

The values are something like :

```
h        w       hw_flag  
5.874  60.5478    0
4.874  40.5478    0
3.874  10.5478    1
2.999  6.5478     1
8.874  90.5478    0
5.111   50.5478   1
6.554   65.5478   0
```

I have initialised two new columns as h_1 and w_1 to 0.

```
X$h_1 <- 0
X$w_1 <- 0
```

Now, what I want is that whenever the hw_flag is 1, then  h_1 and w_1 shall get the entries copied from h and w respectively and then, once the values are copied to h_1 and w_1, the corresponding h and w values should turn 0. I wish to get it all done in one loop.

Right now, I have to write 4 loops for these 4 steps.The code I have worked for is as follows and it is giving me the desired output I wish to have:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(X)){
  if(X$hw_flag[i] == '1') 
    X$h_1[i] <- X$h[i];
}

for(i in 1:nrow(X)){
  if(X$hw_flag[i] == '1') 
    X$w_1[i] <- X$w[i];
}

for(i in 1:nrow(X)){
  if(X$hw_flag[i] == '1') 
    X$h[i] <- 0;
}

for(i in 1:nrow(X)){
  if(X$hw_flag[i] == '1') 
    X$w[i] <- 0;
}

Output :

h        w            hw_flag   h_1   w_1  
5.874  60.5478           0       0    0
4.874  40.5478           0       0    0
0        0               1     3.874  10.5478
0        0               1     2.999  6.5478      
8.874  90.5478           0      0     0
0         0              1     5.111  50.5478  
6.554   65.5478          0       0     0
```

I tried putting all in one if loop but certainly the issue I was facing is that the first step gets executed as expected whereas, the second step doesn't work properly. I tried putting ; and line breaks via Enter but still it didn't work out.
The code I tried was following and it copied the h values to h_1 but in the next step, it did not copy the values of w to w_1 :

```
for(i in 1:nrow(X)) {
  if(X$hw_flag[i] == '1') 
    X$h_1[i] <- X$h[i];
    X$w_1[i] <- X$w[i];
  X$h[i] <- 0;
  X$w[i] <- 0;
  }
```

So, I basically wish to know that how can I put multiple then statements for the same IF- Yes block.

Comment: Try surrounding the commands to be run by the `if` statement in curly braces, in the same way as what you've done for the `for` loop.

Comment: You don’t need to use `;` in R.

Comment: Thanks @rosscova , I somehow missed those braces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for loops. Just find where `hw_flag` equals one, and copy over the data and then override `h` and `w` with zero.

```
xy <- read.table(text = "h        w       hw_flag  
5.874  60.5478    0
                 4.874  40.5478    0
                 3.874  10.5478    1
                 2.999  6.5478     1
                 8.874  90.5478    0
                 5.111   50.5478   1
                 6.554   65.5478   0", header = TRUE)

xy$h_1 <- 0
xy$w_1 <- 0

hwflag1 <- xy$hw_flag == 1
xy[hwflag1, c("h_1", "w_1")] <- xy[hwflag1, c("h", "w")]
xy[hwflag1, c("h", "w")] <- 0

      h       w hw_flag   h_1     w_1
1 5.874 60.5478       0 0.000  0.0000
2 4.874 40.5478       0 0.000  0.0000
3 0.000  0.0000       1 3.874 10.5478
4 0.000  0.0000       1 2.999  6.5478
5 8.874 90.5478       0 0.000  0.0000
6 0.000  0.0000       1 5.111 50.5478
7 6.554 65.5478       0 0.000  0.0000
```

Comment: I would say, "No need to loop **over rows**". Loops over vectors many times can outperform vectorized operations because avoiding matrix conversion and methods dispatching... Just saying :)

Comment: Thanks Roman and @DavidArenburg. This code works well and has lesser complexity than running a loop.

Comment: @DavidArenburg : Can you throw some more insight on the part you said. May be a link for the same can help understanding it better. I'm looking out for a more details version of what you have told for outperforming operations and methods dispatching.

Comment: @PD1 search for "The R Inferno" by Patrick Burns. I should have said "explicit" loops. Everything in our universe is one silly loop.

Answer (score 1):

The commands to be run should really be contained within curly braces:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(X)) { 
    if(X$hw_flag[i] == '1') {
        X$h_1[i] <- X$h[i]
        X$w_1[i] <- X$w[i]
        X$h[i] <- 0
        X$w[i] <- 0
    }
}
```