# Search and replace entries in a dataframe in two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a certain data set in which there are few missing values.
the dataset looks like the following:

```
a b  c0 d0 c1 d1 g   h
1 5  20 10 NA NA 2   NA
1 6  NA NA 8  2  NA  4 
2 5  25 10 NA NA 2.5 NA
2 7  NA NA 2  2  NA  1
2 8  50 10 NA NA 5   NA
3 9  10 10 NA NA 1   NA
3 6  NA NA 8  4  NA  2  
3 10  NA NA 5  1  NA  5
4 5  NA NA 6  2  NA  3
4 11 25 10 NA NA 2.5 NA
```

My data is in the above mentioned format. Column `a` is a kind of time period which is in sequence and has multiple codes corresponding to it. 
Column `b` just shows an item. This item either has a repeated entry in time or has an unique value.
Column `g` and `h` are just the columns made by dividing column `c0`/`d0` = `g` and `c1`/`d1` = `h`. Out here, column `g` holds more importance.

Now, since it is clear that there are few NA and some of the column `b` entries are duplicate whereas rest are unique.

I have to perform the following steps in order to compute the NA's in column 'g':

1. I have to find in the 'column b' that is the entry repetitive or has an unique value.Eg : Entry 6 and 5 are repeated, whereas 7,8 9,10 and 11 are unique.
2. Once it has been found, next step is to that whether there is some value in 'column g' already for the item or not.
3. If there is, then we need to take average of the repetaed value in 'column g' if it's other than NA, like for item 5, I can find that the values are 2 and 2.5 and hence the average of 2.25 should be place in 'column g' for the repeated 5 value at a=4.
4. Now, if there is a repeated value but still column g is NA, then I can simply take the 'column h' value as value of 'column g'.
5. For the non repetitive items, like 9,10,7, etc. since they are unique, just replace the column g entry by column h.

The final output should be as follows:

```
a b  c0 d0 c1 d1 g   h
1 5  20 10 NA NA 2   NA
1 6  NA NA 8  2  4   4 
2 5  25 10 NA NA 2.5 NA
2 7  NA NA 2  2  1   1
2 8  50 10 NA NA 5   NA
3 9  10 10 NA NA 1   NA
3 6  NA NA 8  4  2   2  
3 10 NA NA 5  1  5   5
4 5  NA NA 6  2  2.25 3
4 11 25 10 NA NA 2.5 NA
```

Request you to help me out with it. In case, you have any question in understanding the question, do let me know or even if some more details are required.

Comment: Just a tip -- in the R tag we encourage you to share your data via `dput` to facilitate reproducibility. Also if you're typing code or referencing a value in your data you can use `code format` to make your question more readable (I've tried to help out with the latter). Cheers.

Comment: You also need to show that you've made an effort to solve this yourself before posting here. All I see here is give me the codezzz

Comment: Where did they row at `b == 10` go? And why does `g` at the second appearance of `b == 6` now has `2` instead of `4`?

Comment: Dirty sock : I did make a try but facing issues in implementing the same as of now.

Comment: @DavidArenburg : thanks for pointing that out. A 0 got deleted in b=10 in the expected output. And in the case of b == 6, it is possible to have multiple different values but as long as there isn't any value in column c0 &  d0,  we can ignore it's mean and simply copy it's value from column h to g.

Comment: In your data for the second `b == 6` , `h == 4`, but in the expected output `h == 2`. o where in your explanations you've mentioned altering `h` anywhere

Comment: @Hack-R :Firstly thanks for your tip on presenting the data, appreciate it since I'm a new on stack overflow.I will have a look on how to enter via dput.  And thanks for your solution as well,I will be trying all of them. The only reason I think data.table guy might have down voted probably due to multiple loops. I was also trying on the similar lines and chose to ask it here as in one of my previous questions I was told not to use loops on rows in data frame.Here's a link, in comments I got the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38784392/multiple-then-conditions-in-a-single-if-loop-in-r

Comment: @DavidArenburg : Thanks for pointing that out for h==4.  I missed it and corrected it now. Actually its a huge dataset that I tried covering most of the cases in the dummy data. The basic column Imputation required is for column G. And column h is just c1/d1 so, if values will differ in c1-d1, then column h will have different values and will be copied in G for all NA values for example in case of b==6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reduce it to "one" step once we recognize that when grouped by `b`, duplicates imply that there are more than one row grouped. Therefore, the condition to replace the `NA` values in `g` by the mean of its group (that are not `NA`) is if:

> the number of rows grouped by `b` is greater than one **and** not all of `g` in the group is `NA`

Otherwise, replace the `NA` values in `g` with `h`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, g := if (.N > 1 & !all(is.na(g))) {
                   replace(g, is.na(g), mean(g, na.rm = TRUE)) 
                 } else {
                   replace(g, is.na(g), as.double(h)) 
                 }, by=b][]
##    a  b c0 d0 c1 d1    g  h
## 1: 1  5 20 10 NA NA 2.00 NA
## 2: 1  6 NA NA  8  2 4.00  4
## 3: 2  5 25 10 NA NA 2.50 NA
## 4: 2  7 NA NA  2  2 1.00  1
## 5: 2  8 50 10 NA NA 5.00 NA
## 6: 3  9 10 10 NA NA 1.00 NA
## 7: 3  6 NA NA  8  2 4.00  4
## 8: 3 10 NA NA  5  1 5.00  5
## 9: 4  5 NA NA  6  2 2.25  3
##10: 4 11 25 10 NA NA 2.50 NA
```

Comment: Why would you "reduce this to one step"? For shorter code? I'm well aware of the fact that one can use `if` within the `j` expression but operating on each group will be way less efficient than just operating on a possibly very small subset. All the rest is just verbatim of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your desired output is inconsistent. You have one row missing, column `h` has been altered and hence column `g` at the seventh row looks inconsistent too.

Either-way, following your description, I would do this in two steps.

1. First subset your data only by `b` instances that have dupes and alternate `NA`s by the mean of the rest of the group
2. replace all the `NA`s left by column `h`

I'd suggest `data.table` as it allows comfortable operations on subsets

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[duplicated(b) | duplicated(b, fromLast = TRUE), # operate only on the dupes
          g := replace(g, is.na(g), mean(g, na.rm = TRUE)), by = b] # replace NA by group
df[is.na(g), g := as.double(h)] # subset by NAs and replace with corresponding values in h
df
#     a  b c0 d0 c1 d1    g  h
#  1: 1  5 20 10 NA NA 2.00 NA
#  2: 1  6 NA NA  8  2 4.00  4
#  3: 2  5 25 10 NA NA 2.50 NA
#  4: 2  7 NA NA  2  2 1.00  1
#  5: 2  8 50 10 NA NA 5.00 NA
#  6: 3  9 10 10 NA NA 1.00 NA
#  7: 3  6 NA NA  8  2 4.00  4
#  8: 3 10 NA NA  5  1 5.00  5
#  9: 4  5 NA NA  6  2 2.25  3
# 10: 4 11 25 10 NA NA 2.50 NA
```

Comment: Is a special package really necessary to accomplish something so basic? Especially noting that the question specifies a data.*frame* and this changes the data type. Just throwing that out there FWIW.

Comment: @Hack-R I've said why I've used `data.table` in this case. By group operation in base R are not trivial. Same goes for working with subsets. Changing from `data.frame` to `data.table` and back is seamless using `setDT/setDF`